# A complicated question about $E=mc^2$

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, mass-energy, singularities

I know this is a little outside the normal question and there may not be a direct answer, but it is an interesting thought experiment.

Starting with a supermassive black hole, if you were able to feed in mass without limit, at what point (total mass) would gravity tear apart all the particles in the singularity to the point that all the mass would be converted to energy? I am assuming that matter is considered energy when it is broken down to its simple building blocks.

Comment: Once inside the Schwarzschild horizon, it is immaterial to observers outside whether what went in was "matter" (fermionic stuff with a rest mass) or "pure energy" (bosonic stuff): it all adds to the black hole's mass by the amount $\sqrt{m_0+(p^2/c^2)}$ where $m_0$ is the rest mass and $p$ its momentum (at the horizon). After this, all the body's energy stays inside the horizon. How it interacts with the "singularity" is unknown:  General Relativity will presumably be inaccurate near the singularity and one of the reasons for studying quantum gravity is to answer questions like yours.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance: That would make a good *answer*.

Comment: I'm disappointed by the downvotes.  It's a pretty good question even if it's based on something of a misconception.  I think the misconception that matter is somehow different than energy or that matter can be torn apart into building blocks could also make a good question in of itself.

Answer (score 5):

Once inside the Schwarzschild horizon, it is immaterial to observers outside whether what went in was "matter" (fermionic stuff with a rest mass) or "pure energy" (bosonic stuff): it all adds to the black hole's mass by the amount  $\sqrt{m_0+(p^2/c^2)}$ where $m_0$  is the rest mass and $p$ its momentum (at infinity). After this, all the body's energy stays inside the horizon. How it interacts with the "singularity" is unknown: General Relativity will presumably be inaccurate near the singularity and one of the reasons for studying quantum gravity is to answer questions like yours.

Mass falling into a black hole can radiate enormous amounts of energy, but this is kinetic energy, rather than rest energy, converted to radiation either as charged mass accelerates (recall the [Lamor Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula) and its relativistic broadening through the [Liénard–Wiechert potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential)) or as the molecules of an accelerated gas collide and the whole mass becomes fantastically hot. For a spectacular view of this process witness the five thousand light year long jet from the [Messier 87 Galaxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messier_87).

Comment: Shouldn't that be momentum at infinity instead? The ADM energy of black hole+infalling matter should be conserved, and that's defined at infinity. For the simple Schwarzschild case, orbital energy is generated by Schwarzschild time, which can be interpreted as time of a stationary observer at infinity, and that's the amount that should be added to the black hole's mass-energy. (Also, I disagree with the characterization of 'pure energy'='bosonic', on account of, e.g., helium and alpha particles in some states, etc. Maybe 'massless' would work better, though this use is still a bit inaccurate.)

Comment: @StanLiou You're right - I meant to say at infinity. As for the "energy" *vs.* "matter" I have to confess ignorance as to what one should call what these days without specifying it exactly - it's all the same as far as relativity is concerned. "Matter" tends to imply the Pauli Exclusion Principle to me, but maybe I'm wrong. The OP seems caught up in the idea of conversion of "mass" to "energy" which is but what I'm trying to say is that no matter what conversion happens, the *property* of inertia is still there.

Comment: I'd count helium as matter, even when it forms a Bose-Einstein condensate, so to me basing it on Pauli exclusion seems strange. "Matter" is a strongly context-dependent word, but I'd probably never use "energy" as its complement at all, except perhaps metaphorically ... which works fine for a question like this, especially with the scare quotes. (:

Comment: @StanLiou You're a bit mean making a fifty year old physicist realize he doesn't really know what "matter" means :) Anyhow, I got to cite M87 my favourite celestial body M87, which is the coolest thing about this answer IMO.

Answer (score 1):

> I am assuming that matter is considered energy when it is broken down to its simple building blocks.

If that's your criteria for being "considered energy", then at least classically the singularity of a black hole of any mass whatsoever will do this, simply because the gravitational tidal forces diverge to infinity near those types of (curvature) singularities. Roughly, for any material objects, the difference in gravitational effects between its different parts will be arbitrarily large, tearing it apart before some time before reaching the singularity.

What happens near the singularity quantum-mechanically is not really understood at this time.

But there is no rigorous notion for when matter is considered energy simply because energy is a *property* of physical systems and physical things, whether particles or fields.